# Application created using create-react-app not working properly after cloning from github

Tags: reactjs, git, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

So I pushed the application I created using `create-react-app` to github in an organisation repo.After cloning it
I ran 
`npm init`
`npm install`
and then ran `npm start`. But when the server loaded
it showed `localhost:3000/organisation-name/repo-name` with one letter less from the repo-name(for example,if repo-name was newapp it was like `localhost:3000/organisation-name/newap`) and also the program is not working.
I also tried at `localhost:3000` but it is not working.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. This was working on your development environment but not in a "production" environment. Try grep for all "newap" apparences in the clone: you might have committed something wrong, and have it working in your dirty development environment.

Comment: It seems the problem was running `npm init` after cloning. I tried again without running `npm init` and it worked.

Comment: `npm init` is for initializing new projects, it will create the package.json. You don't need that when cloning you already have a package.json.